# GDI Paths in WM 6.x

Tags: c++, graphics, windows-mobile, gdi+, gdi

It looks like functions like `BeginPath` `EndPath` and `StrokeAndFillPath` do not exist in Windows Mobile. Does anyone know if they have been replaced by a different method or if there is another way of achieving this? I am trying to write a text on an image that should look like this:
[image]

Thank you

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Paths / Regions are part of [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx). Windows Mobile, only (unofficially) supports a [restricted set of features](http://www.ernzo.com/LibGdiplus.aspx) of GDI+. Take a look on this [nice article from OpenNetCF guys.](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/10/31/using-gdi-on-windows-mobile.aspx)

Comment: Even the [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx) in WM 6.x does not support 'paths'. Functions like 'GdipAddPathString' returns 'NotImplemented'. Any ideas?

Comment: I think only simple geometrical figures (rectangles, circles, etc) are allowed, but I could not find the proper reference in the doc to support this assertion. This is somehow mentioned in the article from OpenNetCf that I added to my answer.